# laravel: remove folder directory in url shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, deployment

I just recently deploy my Laravel app and I want to remove the folder directory. Example:

> example.com/laravel/anotherfolder/home

I want to remove the laravel because that is the folder

I have tried searching on google but they don't work, here is my `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^laravel/(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your shared host provider, you need go on your control panel and change the public directory to `laravel/public`.

Another solution would be to replace the current public folder by a symlink which links to `laravel/public`. You'll need an SSH access for this solution.